# Fullcalendar: How to render time from json url - type error hasTime()

Tags: angularjs, json, fullcalendar

How can I render time on my fullcalendar from a json url (/comments)? It's showing "object Object" where time is supposed to show. What's the correct way of pulling the time from a json url?

**json example from url**

`{"Title": "qwerty", "Description": "asdf", "IsFullDay": null, "EndAt": "2016-09-21T09:10:15.549000", "StartAt": "2016-09-21T09:10:15.549000"}`

**fullcalendar**

[image]

**error from "fullcalendar.min"**

[image]

[image]

**controller.js**

```
function populate() {
        clearCalendar();
        $http.get('/comments', {
            cache: true,
            params: {},
        }).then(function (data) {
            $scope.projects.slice(0, $scope.projects.length);
            angular.forEach(data.data, function (value) {
                $scope.projects.push({
                    // id : value.ProjectID,
                    title: value.Title,
                    description: value.Description,
                    start: new Date(value.StartAt),
                    end: new Date(value.EndAt),
                    allDay: value.IsFullDay,
                    stick: true
                });
            });
        });
}

//configure calendar

$scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar: {
         eventSources:{
              url: '/comments',
         },
         height: 500,
         editable: true,
         displayEventTime: true,
         header: {
            left: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'today prev,next'
         },
         timeFormat : {
            month: ' ', //for hide on month view
            agenda: 'h:mm: t'
         },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end){
            var fromDate = moment(start).format('DD/MM/YYYY LT');
            var endDate  = moment(end).format('DD/MM/YYYY LT');

            $scope.NewProject = {
                ProjectID : 0,
                StartAt : fromDate,
                EndAt : endDate,
                IsFullDay : false,
                Title : '',
                Description: ''
            }
            $scope.ShowModal()
        },
```

Comment: Expand the error and see where in your code it is originating from.

Comment: @Ryan89 it is coming from fullcalendar.min cant change that code of course

Comment: No click the arrow on the left, and follow the trace to where in your code it originated from.

Comment: only coming from fullcalendar.min and jquery.min. I have updated the snap shots above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in this case was simply to (un-objectify) change

```
timeFormat : {
        month: ' ', //for hide on month view
        agenda: 'h:mm: t'
     },
```

to

```
timeFormat : 'h:mm: t'
```

or whichever format you want OR simply remove `timeFormat` altogether (will automatically resolve to its default)

Answer (score 0):

In your populate function your start and end date are made using Javascript Date object, that will not work with fullCalendar, it needs moment date object. Change the following

```
start: new Date(value.StartAt),
end: new Date(value.EndAt),
```

to this

```
start: moment(value.StartAt),
end: moment(value.EndAt),
```